# rqt_image_view as input in opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ros

i'm new to ros and opencv. However i want to know, is there any way to get the rqt_image_view output, so i can use it directly on opencv. Normally to get picture from file it will look like this

```
image = imread("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

but now, can i somehow change "image.jpg" to output from rqt_image_view with output from rqt_image_view like this

[image: rqt_image_view from ros]

***The idea here, to get an image from ros and then process the output image with separated opencv code.***

Comment: check : http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython

Comment: The sample at --> 4: An example ROS node --> http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython should be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you need the `cv_bridge` package for this.

Some additional information:

The `rqt_image_view` node subscribes to an image topic to display the image/video stream, in your case the image topic is `/video_192_168_20_105_5000`.
`cv_bridge` lets you directly convert the images published to the ROS image topic to opencv images during runtime, so you don't need to open the image from file. That would require you to save the ROS image to a file and reopen it in opencv.

Comment: Yeah thx, i did convert the rqt image first with a subscriber, then edit it with opencv, lastly i just convert the opencv image output to ros again.